# Show new form every five seconds

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli, showdialog

I have a problem with runing new windows every for example five seconds.
I tried this code:

```
private: System::Void start_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 Form1^ slowo = gcnew Form1();
                 while(1)
                 {
                     slowo->ShowDialog();
                     Sleep(5000);
                 }
             }
```

New form is showing, next when user will close new window I'm waiting 5 sec and run window again.
But it dosen't working. Form1 is showing only once.

Comment: Put the instantiation line **inside** the while loop...

Comment: Also, why put this in the Load() event?...the `start` Form will never show so why have it in the first place?  What is the end goal here?

Comment: @Idle_Mind: thanks for help, now it's work. I know that `start` will never show - it was my target - i want just show `Form1` every x minutes.